# Problema com TinyMCE Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

Estou criando uma aplicação com rails e fiz a integração do editor TinyMCE pela [gem](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails)

O processo de instalação rolou tranquilo. Testei no servidor local e deu certo na primeira vez. Mas quando abri novamente o formulário a area de edição não aparece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Darshan provavelmente você está usando o TinyMCE num modal, certo?

Se sim é por quê você precisa iniciar o TinyMCE por javascript nesse modal, para que ele busque no servidor as dependências JS e CSS deles que são carregadas dinamicamente.

Eu já passei por isso uma vez e foi assim que eu contornei isso. Acredito que deve ter alguma configuração também para que o TinyMCE não seja inicializado todas as vezes quando abrimos um modal.